# Summarise table with boolean columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

A table contains 3 columns. The first col contains all items (as.characters) in groupA. The second and third col contain Boolean vectors, indicating if the groupB and groupC also contain the item (TRUE) or not (FALSE).

How do you summarise the table to known how many of the items present in groupA are present or absent in groupB and groupC?

In the results table, it should be counted how often groupA contains an entry not present in B or C (FALSE, FALSE), present in both or present in either B or C.
The original table has thousands of entries, not just the few from the example data.

A dplyr solution would be appreciated.

Example data:

```
example <- data.frame(
 groupA = c('shshs', 'ihdfeowf', 'woefiewfh', 'awofjqweofj', 'hdhd', 'dudj'),
 groupB = c(T, T ,F, F, T, F),
 groupC = c(T, F, F, T, T, T))

expected_result <- data.frame(
 groupA = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
 groupB = c(F, T, T, F),
 groupC = c(F, T, F, T))
```

Comment: Were there any errors in your code or did you encounter problems?

Comment: I don't know how to get to the table: expected_result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you could use.

```
example %>% 
group_by(groupB, groupC) %>% 
summarize(groupA = n()) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
select(groupA, groupB, groupC)
```

With following output (as tibble as we use dplyr but you can convert to traditional data.frame).

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  groupA groupB groupC
  <int> <lgl>  <lgl> 
1      1 FALSE  FALSE 
2      2 FALSE  TRUE  
3      1 TRUE   FALSE 
4      2 TRUE   TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```r
table(example$groupB, example$groupC) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  (`[`)(c(3, 1, 2)) |>
  setNames(names(example))
#>   groupA groupB groupC
#> 1      1  FALSE  FALSE
#> 2      1   TRUE  FALSE
#> 3      2  FALSE   TRUE
#> 4      2   TRUE   TRUE
```

Or, if you are using R < 4.1.0, then you could do:

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(table(example$groupB, example$groupC))[c(3, 1, 2)],
        names(example))
#>   groupA groupB groupC
#> 1      1  FALSE  FALSE
#> 2      1   TRUE  FALSE
#> 3      2  FALSE   TRUE
#> 4      2   TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't work. Please indicate if you use specific packages (" |> " seems to come from a package?)

Comment: @SebastianHesse this is R's native pipe operator, which has been a part of R since version 4.1.0. This was released almost 2 years ago, so the `|>` operator has become a very common part of R lexicon, and it doesn't require any packages. You must have an older version of R installed. I will update to include a version using the older syntax, but you should consider updating R if possible, and learning about the native pipe operator.

Comment: shame on me, seems im too deep into tidyR and the %>% pipe. Excuse my knowledge gap. (actually it makes sense that I missed it, I was in a clinical rotation the last 2 years :) Thanks for letting me know! Still, the code won't deliver the expected results as it lists every item in A individually instead of counting them.

Comment: @SebastianHesse no it doesn't - there are only four rows in the resulting data frame compared to six in the input data frame. The format of the table is exactly as in the expected output you provided. It's a simple truth table of the occurences of TRUE and FALSE in the input data frame. Can you update your question to include the expected output, since the expected output I have given is the expected output in your original question, and you are now saying this is not what you want?

Comment: You are correct, I edited my question. The original table has thousands of entries.

Comment: @SebastianHesse your question doesn't seem to have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` to summarize the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>% 
  mutate(groupB = ifelse(groupB, "True", "False"),
         groupC = ifelse(groupC, "True", "False")) %>% 
  group_by(groupB, groupC) %>% 
  summarize(groupA = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(groupA = c(1, 2, 1, 2)) %>% 
  arrange(groupB, groupC) %>% 
  select(groupA, groupB, groupC)
```

Expected Output

```
  groupA groupB groupC
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1      1 False  False 
2      2 False  True  
3      1 True   False 
4      2 True   True
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is hardcoding the results of groupA. Instead, this should be a counted results (the original table has thousands of entries)